# Regular expression in grep to find a word

Tags: regex, grep

I have a sample.txt file as below:

```
1.hi _plane_ is
2.hi airplane is
3.hi plane is
4.hi _plane- is
5.hi :plane: is
plane
there is a plane here
```

I'd like to find a word "plane" not inside other word, say "airplane",
so after grep, output will be just as below(only line 2 will be filtered out)

```
1.hi _plane_ is
3.hi plane is
4.hi _plane- is
5.hi :plane: is
plane
there is a plane here
```

I tried:

```
grep -w "plane" sample.txt
grep "\bplane\b\|\Bplane\B" sample.txt
```

But the output are not match what I expect.
how actually should I use grep to get the correct result?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
egrep -v '[[:alpha:]]+plane|plane[[:alpha:]]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep "(^|[^a-zA-Z])plane([^a-zA-Z]|$)" sample.txt
```

The problem with `\b` is that underscore character `_` is counted as a "word character", so `\bplane\b` doesn't match `_plane_`

Comment: but this will lost line 6 only "plane"

Comment: @CSJ Didn't notice that one - I fixed the regex accordingly. See new version of regex

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -w plane sample.txt
```

Scratch that; `grep -w` counts underscore as part of a word, so it is no good in this context.